# Wind direction statistics

Tags: wind, statistics

I evaluate the performance of the model through the computation of statistical parameter such as bias, R, IOA and other. (i compare it with in situ measurements)
However, wind direction (range 0 to 360 in degrees) has difficult characteristics. Thus, I would like to ask if you know statistics tailored to wind direction.

Thanks

Comment: I've run into this issue with latitude and longitude. I solved that issue by treating them as 3D points on the sphere so there's no issue when longitude changes from -180 to +180 at the antimeridian, and so that the differing width of a degree of longitude isn't an issue. You can do something similar by using x and y coordinates

Comment: Probably this might be helpful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44621/calculate-average-wind-direction

Comment: @BarryCarter if I understand well, you propose to get a circle in cartesian coordinates like sin and cos. Interesting idea. To be fair, the link in mathematics by dimfalk states (and it is logical) that apart from the wind direction, the wind speed as absolute value is also important.

Comment: @dimfalk yes, thanks, the idea of the vector is interesting, but mean value is proposed. I want to evaluate the performance of a model, thus I do need something more. But, I could use the idea of the vector, with other ways.

Comment: @DimitrisTsiaousidis Yes, that's one way to solve the "discontinuity at 0/360" issue